# Calculating partial distances from whole segment in grid using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, clip, vector-grid, calculate-values

I am using QGIS and trying to find a way to calculate partial distances of lines in a grid.

In the left part of the picture you can see the sum of the line lengths within the grid cell (108.96...), and the length of the whole yellow line/segment that intersect it in black (146.37...).

How do I trim the yellow line to multi-lines which will show the proportional length in each cell (i.e 108.96+...+Len(Xn) =146.37)?

[image: map]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself - It is 2 steps process:
1. intersect the lines with the grid layer so all lines are split into segments.
2. Using field calculator: $length of the line layer